# Error Creating Control on asp.net video

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I was trying to embed an asp.net video control using my visual web developer 2008 express ed. which originally doesn't have a built-in asp.net video control on its toolbox. I added the asp.net video control on the toolbox after I extracted the zip compressed folder that I downloaded. I was able to add the three asp.net video controls(WindowsMedia,Realplayer,Quicktime) from the downloaded files on the toolbox. At first, it was working when I tried to drag the WindowsMedia control from the toolbox onto the page but suddenly when I changed it using Realplayer it will now display an Error Creating Control on the control after dragging into the page. The error says:

> The server tag 'ASPNetVideo:RealPlayer' is ambiguous. Please modify
>   the associated registration that is causing ambiguity and pick a new
>   tag prefix.

So, I keep on changing the control from WindowsMedia to Quicktime and still giving the same error. Here's my source code below for more reference:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="ASPNetVideo.NET2.AJAX" namespace="ASPNetVideo" tagprefix="ASPNetVideo" %>

<%@ Register assembly="ASPNetVideo.NET3" namespace="ASPNetVideo" tagprefix="ASPNetVideo" %>

<%@ Register assembly="System.Web.Extensions" namespace="System.Web.UI" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

<title>Untitled Page</title>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id = "mydiv" runat="server">

    <br />

    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <br />

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" Width="82px" OnClick = "Button1_Click" />

    <br />

     <br />

    <br />

    <ASPNetVideo:RealPlayer ID="RealPlayer1" runat="server" >

    </ASPNetVideo:RealPlayer>
    <br />


</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please advise...Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%@ Register assembly="ASPNetVideo.NET2.AJAX" namespace="ASPNetVideo" tagprefix="ASPNetVideo" %>

<%@ Register assembly="ASPNetVideo.NET3" namespace="ASPNetVideo" tagprefix="ASPNetVideo" %>
```

`RealPlayer` is most probably defined in both those assemblies. Try with only one of them and remove the other register.

You can also assign different namespaces to the two assemblies and then you wouldn't be getting an error once you resolve the ambiguity:

```
<%@ Register assembly="ASPNetVideo.NET2.AJAX" namespace="ASPNetVideo" tagprefix="ASPNetVideo" %>

<%@ Register assembly="ASPNetVideo.NET3" namespace="ASPNetVideo2" tagprefix="ASPNetVideo" %>
```

Comment: I tried removing one of the assemblies but still give me more errors:

Comment: Errors List:

Error    1    The type 'ASPNetVideo.RealPlayer' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website5\74862b8f\8d02a72\assembly\dl3\7a0f991b\4893b218_a14cce01\ASPNetVideo.NET3.DLL' and 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website5\74862b8f\8d02a72\assembly\dl3\28cdd191\fa205f18_a14cce01\ASPNetVideo.NET2.AJAX.DLL'    C:\Documents and Settings\Mark Tim\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite5\Default.aspx    1    1    C:\...\WebSite5\

Comment: Error    2    The type 'ASPNetVideo.RealPlayer' exists in both 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website5\74862b8f\8d02a72\assembly\dl3\7a0f991b\4893b218_a14cce01\ASPNetVideo.NET3.DLL' and 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website5\74862b8f\8d02a72\assembly\dl3\28cdd191\fa205f18_a14cce01\ASPNetVideo.NET2.AJAX.DLL'    c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\website5\74862b8f\8d02a72\App_Web_zyatvvob.0.cs    295

Comment: @timmack You are probably using both assemblies at different places in your project. The issue is, as I described, that you need to resolve the correct reference through the assembly that you want to be using, because with the previous registers you had both assemblies registered to the same namespace.